# Pandas - Find the index for the first time a condition is true

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks something like this:

```
example = pd.Series([0,0,0,2,2,0], index = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005])
```

How do I find the index corresponding to the first time that a condition is true?

For example, I want to find the index corresponding to the first nonzero entry, which in the example data is 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
example.ne(0).idxmax()
#2003
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `nonzero`

```
example.index[example.nonzero()[0][0]]
Out[267]: 2003
```

Comment: Wow.  We are on a `nonzero` kick today.

Comment: @ScottBoston yep :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
example[example != 0].index[0]
```